# Bootstrap 3 - Glyphicon over image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to make a thumbnail with bootstrap3.

How can I make this, I mean to put this zoom-in glyphicon over the image?:
(sorry for paint shop :D)

[image: Desired:]

Actually, I've got this:

[image]

with the following code:

```
<div class="thumbnail PNET-thumbcolor">
 <div class="PNET-cursor-hand center-block text-center">
  <img data-src="holder.js/140x140" alt="Producto">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="caption">...
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make this with CSS only, without touching the bootstrap style?

Thanks in advance!
Please comment or ask if you need more information and/or improve! :)

UPDATE:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Leandro1981/AKwb4/1/

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle, so we can try on your code. :-)

Comment: @LucaDetomi thanks! I did it, I've to import the holder.js library but there is! (I'm working in the fiddle improvement)

Comment: I don't see gray box.... but only a blue bar...

Comment: yep updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Leandro1981/AKwb4/1/

Comment: Do you have some problems about set a fixed width to container "PNET-thumbcolor" ??

Comment: no, please be free to change it as you need it ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edit only CSS, adding a position relative to Lens icon, and set a fixed width to container.

```
.PNET-cursor-hand
{
    width:140px;
}

.PNET-thumbcolor .glyphicon-zoom-in
{
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    right:5px;
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
}
```

Here the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AKwb4/2/)

Comment: perfect!!! u get it :D I was broke my brain trying to make the container float and the icon fixed. forza azurra! :D